# UTF-8 is an Encoding or a Document Character Set?

Tags: html, encoding, character-encoding, w3c

According with [W3C Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/charset.html) says that every aplicattion requires its document character set (Not be confused with Character Encoding).

> A document character set consists of:
>
> - A Repertoire: A set of abstract characters, such as the Latin letter "A", the Cyrillic letter "I", the Chinese character meaning "water", etc.
> - Code positions: A set of integer references to characters in the repertoire.
>
> Each document is a sequence of characters from the repertoire.
>
> Character Encoding is: 
>       How those characters may be represented

When i save a file in Windows notepad im guessing that this are the "Document Character Sets":

- ANSI
- UNICODE
- UNICODE BIG ENDIAN
- UTF-8

Simple 3 questions:

I want to know if those are the "document character sets". And if they are,

1. Why is UTF-8 on the list? UTF-8 is not supposed to be an **encoding**?

   If im not wrong with all this stuff:
2. Are there another Document Character Sets that Windows do not allow you to define?
3. How to define another document character sets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my understanding:

- ANSI is both a character set and an encoding of that character set.
- Unicode is a character set; the the encoding in question is probably UTF-16. An alternative encoding of the same character set is big-endian UTF-16, which is probably what the third option is referring to.
- UTF-8 is an encoding of Unicode.

The purpose of that dropdown in the Save dialog is really to select both a character set and an encoding for it, but they've been a little careless with the naming of the options.

(Technically, though, an encoding just maps integers to byte sequences, so any encoding could be used with any character set that is small enough to "fit" the encoding. However, the UTF-* encodings are designed with Unicode in mind.)

Also, see [Joel on Software's mandatory article on the subject](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: think that the 4 that im refereing are "Document Character sets"? why UTF-8 is on the list if is an encoding. or im wrong with the document character sets?

Comment: @nEAnnam: No, the term _Document Character Set_ as used by the W3C article seems to refer to only the definition of _which characters exist_ and _the integer code that belongs to each character_. In order to save a file, you need to know both the character set _and_ the encoding (which is mentioned in 5.2 in the article). The dropdown box you are referring to contains _combinations of character sets and encodings_, but they are _incorrectly and inconsistently named_.

Comment: @nEAnnam: More correct dropdown item names would be "Charset: ANSI / Encoding: ANSI", "Charset: Unicode / Encoding: UTF-16", "Charset: Unicode / Encoding: big-endian UTF-16", and "Charset: Unicode / Encoding: UTF-8". Optionally, one could just list the encodings, since an encoding usually "belongs to" a single charset: "ANSI" / "UTF-16", "big-endian UTF-16", and "UTF-8".

Comment: So all the problem are this freaking windows senseless options. Ill put you the answered because you clear the big doubt. Also thanks to Oded.

Comment: @nEAnnam: Thanks. Yes, the badly named options surely contributed to the confusion in this case. Read the article, though, and you'll be able to see through bad wording yourself next time (I knew nothing about charsets and encoding until I read that article). :-)

Answer (score 1):

[UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is a character encoding that is also used to specify a character set for HTML and other textual documents. It is one of several Unicode encodings (UTF-16 is another).

To answer your questions:

- It is on the list because Microsoft decided to implement it in notepad.
- There are many other character sets, though defining your own is not useful, so not really possible.
- You can't define other character sets to save with notepad. Try using a programmers editor such as notepad++ that will give you more character sets to use.

Comment: UTF-8 is A "Document character set"? (not confuse with character encoding)

Comment: -1. UTF-8 is an _encoding_ that specifies how code points from the Unicode character set can be represented as byte sequences.

Comment: people confuse it, and all the web is full of useless information :(

Comment: @nEAnnam: Very true. However, the article I linked to in my answer is an excellent source of information. :-)

Comment: @Oded: Downvote removed after your edit (though "used as a character set for HTML" makes it sound like that's the only thing UTF-8 can be used for...)

Comment: @nEAnnam - Not sure what you mean. Can you rephrase?

Comment: @Oded now you are answering my questions.